# Function works when returning true or false but not when returning 0 or 1

Tags: php

```
function date2_in_the_past($day, $month, $year)
{
    $datestring = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day;
    if (date ('Y-m-d', strtotime($datestring)) < date('Y-m-d', strtotime("now",time()))) {
        $b = 1;  **// I want $b = true**;
    }
    else { $b = 0; **// I want $b = false;** }

    return $b;
}
//echo date2_in_the_past(24, 10, 2013);     // returns 0
```

But it doesn't return anything with `$b = true` or `$b = false;`. Any idea how I could make the function work assigning `$b` to a boolean rather than writing `'==1'` or `'==0'`?

Comment: That really doesn't make sense. How are you _testing_ what it returns when returning the booleans? In what context are you calling the function?

Comment: Oh wait, you're trying to `echo` the result directly.  `false` has no string equivalent and will display nothing when `echo`'d out.  `true` will display `1` when you echo it.  Instead of `echo`, use a condition that deals properly with the boolean: `if (date2_in_the_past(...)) { echo 'yes...';}`

Answer (score 2):

the problem is in the echo you commented. if you want to check if a variable is either true or false you should use

```
var_dump($variable)
```

instead of

```
echo $variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the variables as bool:

```
 function date2_in_the_past($day, $month, $year)
    {
     $datestring = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day;
     if (date ('Y-m-d', strtotime($datestring)) < date('Y-m-d', strtotime("now",time()))) {
        bool $b = true;  **// I want $b = true**;
    }
    else { bool $b = false; **// I want $b = false;** }

    return $b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- return true or false and use operators === and !== to test return value
- when you echo Boolean variables on the browser you don't see true or false you will see 1 for true and nothing for false to print it write boolean as string like this:

  $var = false;
  if($var === true)
      echo 'true';
  else if($var === false)
      echo 'false';